# R dplyr: Write list output to dataframe

Tags: r, list, dataframe, dplyr

Suppose I have the following function

```
SlowFunction = function(vector){
  return(list(
    mean =mean(vector),
    sd  = sd(vector)
    ))
  }
```

And I would like to use dplyr:summarise to write the results to a dataframe:

```
iris %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(Species) %>% 
  dplyr::summarise(
    mean = SlowFunction(Sepal.Length)$mean,
    sd   = SlowFunction(Sepal.Length)$sd
    )
```

Does anyone have a suggestion how I can do this by calling "SlowFunction" once instead of twice? (In my code "SlowFunction" is a slow function that I have to call many times.) Without splitting "SlowFunction" in two parts of course. So actually I would like to somehow fill multiple columns of a dataframe in one statement.

Comment: Will this help https://stackoverflow.com/a/52413631/786542?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An option is to use to store the output of `SlowFunction` in a `list` column of `data.frame`s and then to use `unnest`

```
iris %>%
    group_by(Species) %>%
    summarise(res = list(as.data.frame(SlowFunction(Sepal.Length)))) %>%
    unnest()
## A tibble: 3 x 3
#  Species     mean    sd
#  <fct>      <dbl> <dbl>
#1 setosa      5.01 0.352
#2 versicolor  5.94 0.516
#3 virginica   6.59 0.636
```

Comment: Thanks, I've compared the answers and this one is in my case by far the fastest. It is 2x faster than using "do" and 2.5x faster than using group_map!

Answer (score 4):

Without changing your current `SlowFunction` one way is to use `do`

```
library(dplyr)

iris %>% 
   group_by(Species) %>% 
   do(data.frame(SlowFunction(.$Sepal.Length)))

#  Species     mean    sd
#  <fct>      <dbl> <dbl>
#1 setosa      5.01 0.352
#2 versicolor  5.94 0.516
#3 virginica   6.59 0.636
```

---

Or with `group_split` + `purrr::map_dfr`

```
bind_cols(Species = unique(iris$Species), iris %>%
     group_split(Species) %>%
     map_dfr(~SlowFunction(.$Sepal.Length)))
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use `group_map` if you are using `dplyr 0.8.0` or later. The output from `SlowFunction` needs to be converted to a data frame.

```
library(dplyr)

iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  group_map(~SlowFunction(.x$Sepal.Length) %>% as.data.frame())
# # A tibble: 3 x 3
# # Groups:   Species [3]
#   Species     mean    sd
#   <fct>      <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 setosa      5.01 0.352
# 2 versicolor  5.94 0.516
# 3 virginica   6.59 0.636
```

Answer (score 3):

We can change the `SlowFunction` to return a `tibble` and

```
SlowFunction = function(vector){
  tibble(
     mean =mean(vector),
      sd  = sd(vector)
     )
   }
```

and then `unnest` the `summarise` output in a `list`

```
iris %>% 
    group_by(Species) %>% 
    summarise(out = list(SlowFunction(Sepal.Length))) %>%
    unnest
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#  Species     mean    sd
#  <fct>      <dbl> <dbl>
#1 setosa      5.01 0.352
#2 versicolor  5.94 0.516
#3 virginica   6.59 0.636
```