# Multiply column values per group in r

Tags: r, frame

I have a data frame as following:

```
 id     weight     value
231      50         0.6
231      50         0.43
420      30         0.86
420      30         0.12
```

How can I multiply all values per each id and weight to have the following table:

```
id     weight     value
231     50       0.6*0.43
420     30       0.86*0.12
```

Comment: It's not clear exactly what you mean. Why not just `df$weight * df$value`?

Comment: @AllanCameron I made some edits in my question.

Comment: There are a lot of SO posts on summary statistics by group, and you should be able to adapt them to use `prod` instead of functions like `sum`, `mean`, `min`, etc. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1660124/5325862), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9847054/5325862), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52413271/5325862) for starters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `prod()` to multiply all the values in its arguments.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(id, weight) %>%
  summarise(prod = prod(value))

# # A tibble: 2 x 3
# # Groups:   id [2]
#      id weight  prod
#   <int>  <int> <dbl>
# 1   231     50 0.258
# 2   420     30 0.103
```

Or a base way

```
aggregate(value ~ id + weight, df, prod)
```

Answer (score 0):

With `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(Prod = prod(value)), .(id, weight)]
```